# Flex item disappears when media query is applied

Tags: html, css, canvas, flexbox

**UPDATE**
Using the link in Ezra Siton answer, I changed the media query display to block and the problem is solved!

In my html code, I have a parent column flexbox with two children. The second child is itself another flexbox with four divs.

I've placed a canvas in each div and further I will display some charts in them. 
The child flexbox is wrapped in large screens so a 2x2 grid is displayed. But in smaller screens, e.g. tablets or smartphones, the flexbox decoration should be changed to no-wrap column:

```css
.inst-data {
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px dotted orangered;
  z-index: 100;
}

.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid-item {
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: orchid;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .grid-container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .grid-item {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inst-data shadow">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h2 class="text-center border-bottom my-2" style="height: 10%; width: 100%;">Title</h2>
    <div class="grid-container" id="ch-div">
      <canvas id="buy-chart" width="200" height="200" class="grid-item"></canvas>
      <canvas id="net-chart" width="200" height="200" class="grid-item"></canvas>
      <canvas id="stock-chart" width="200" height="200" class="grid-item"></canvas>
      <canvas id="price-chart" width="200" height="200" class="grid-item"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I test the media query the top canvas is disappeared and is unreachable even with the scrollbar.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

First, your code is "**dirty**" (Endless ideas/tricks/overflow/flex any property out there :) -- **for very simple grid layout** = **unexpected bugs**)

Why not using a simple flexbox grid? 
https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-flexbox-grids/

About your "chaos bug" - before - the blue card (First col) goes out of the screen because of these two lines:

```
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

#### snippet

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  border: 5px solid red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: orchid;
}
```

```html
<h2>The blue box out of the screen</h2>
<div class="inst-data shadow">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h2 class="text-center border-bottom my-2" style="height: 10%; width: 100%;">Title</h2>
    <div class="grid-container" id="ch-div">
      <canvas id="buy-chart" style="background: blue;" width="200" height="200" class="grid-item">1</canvas>
      <canvas id="net-chart" width="200" height="200" class="grid-item">2</canvas>
      <canvas id="stock-chart" width="200" height="200" class="grid-item">3</canvas>
      <canvas id="price-chart" style="background: red;" width="200" height="200" class="grid-item">4</canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Change to top** ==> fix your issue (But again maybe use diff code approach):

```
  align-content: top;
  justify-content: center;
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: top;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: orchid;
}
```

```html
  <div class="inst-data shadow">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <h2 class="text-center border-bottom my-2" style="height: 10%; width: 100%;">Title</h2>
      <div class="grid-container" id="ch-div">
        <canvas id="buy-chart" style="background: blue;" width="200" height="200" class="grid-item">1</canvas>
        <canvas id="net-chart" width="200" class="grid-item">2</canvas>
        <canvas id="stock-chart" width="200"  class="grid-item">3</canvas>
        <canvas id="price-chart" style="background: red;"  class="grid-item">4</canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Using the link you provided, I changed the media query display to block and the problem is solved!

Comment: Great :) No need to update the Q. You could mark the answer as solution :) By the way, great short course related to flexbox (Again because you use too many styles): https://scrimba.com/g/gflexbox